Python - Kill an Active Subprocess Running in its Own Thread
I have a Python application that starts a subprocess that runs a bash script in another thread and in a separate shell. Note that this script starts a REST service and thus it does not terminate until its explicitly told to (e.g. using crl+c).
I would like to be able to kill the subprocess as well. However, self.subprocess.kill() does not seem to do anything at all. I've tried self.subprocess.terminate() as well. However, the script continues to run as normal.
from subprocess import Popen
import threading

class ProcessManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.process = None

    def run_process(self):
        self.process = Popen("start; sh script.sh", shell=True)

    def kill_process(self):
        self.process.kill()


process_manager = ProcessManager()

thread = threading.Thread(target=process_manager.run_process, args=[])
thread.start()

process_manager.kill_process()

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the fact that I have start; in my command. This was the only way I could force the bash script to be executed in a separate shell than the one that's running the Python application. Using shell=True on its own did not do the trick.
Lastly, the reason for calling run_process in a separate thread is because this method is blocking. As my Python application continues to be built, I will add another similar method runn_process2 that executes another bash script concurrently.


import os
import signal
import threading
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

class ProcessManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.process = None
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def run_process(self):
        with self.lock:
            # Start the process in a new session (own process group)
            # Using shell=True is tricky because it can spawn child processes
            # This preexec_fn=os.setsid creates a new process group for the process, which can then be terminated to terminate all child processes as well.
            self.process = Popen("sh script.sh", shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)

    def kill_process(self):
        with self.lock:
            if self.process:
                try:
                    # Terminate the entire process group
                    os.killpg(os.getpgid(self.process.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
                except OSError as e:
                    print(f"Error killing process: {e}")
                self.process = None

process_manager = ProcessManager()

# Start the subprocess in a separate thread
thread = threading.Thread(target=process_manager.run_process)
thread.start()

# Add a small delay or wait for some condition if needed before killing the process
# time.sleep(10)

process_manager.kill_process()



I see module 'os' has no attribute 'setsid'. I'm running a Windows machine if that helps.

Ah, that will only work on Linux. on Windows, you can use the CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP flag to create a new process group, unchecked so far.

Even with this flag, removing start; from the command does not execute the script in a new shell.
